# Reference request for quadratic forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, quadratic-forms

I am a graduate student  of Mathematics and we have a course in this semester on linear algebra which includes bilinear forms and quadratic forms.The following are the things we need to study:

$1.$ Change of basis in bilinear form.

$2.$Quadratic forms and polarisation.

$3.$ Normal form.

$4.$Positive definite forms.

$5.$ Sylvester's law of inertia.

$6.$ Matrix of positive definite form.

Our course instructor is following the book by Vinberg but it is difficult for me.Can someone suggest any text or lecture note on quadratic form that discusses these topics?Also I would be grateful if someone suggests some problems on these topics.

Comment: Dummit and Foote covers all of these subjects, although not all in detail. Might be worth taking a peek at.

Comment: @DonThousand I have seen dummit foote ,it does not discuss these in as detail as I want.

Comment: Standard more advanced linear algebra texts are Hoffman/Kunze and Friedberg/Insel/Spence.

Comment: if you are willing to do a lot of exercises Artin's *Algebra* chapter on Bilinear Forms (1st edition in particular) covers just about all this though "normal form" is an overloaded term which could mean many things so I don't have an opinion on 3